# ABPersonPickerNavigationController and UITabbarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, addressbook

How can we use use `ABPersonPickerNavigationController` on suppose the third tab of the `UITabbarcontroller`.

Actually I am showing all Address book contacts in this controller...so I use `ABPersonPickerNavigationController`

Currently I am using this code but when we click on third tab of `UITabbarcontroller`..  this controller will present and we can not see that UITabbar..

Here is my code..

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // creating the picker
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];

    // place the delegate of the picker to the controll
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

    // showing the picker
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:NO];

    // releasing
    [picker release];   
}
```

So what can I do so that both the `ABPersonPickerNavigationController` and `UITabbarcontroller` can be seen...

Please help me to solve this problem..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: have you tried bringSubviewToFront with tabbar as arg

Comment: @xs2bush doing UITabbarcontroller based application so can u plz give me some code

Comment: brother, you'll have to write the code yourself....i can just give you ideas :|

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:NO];
```

Try this

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[[picker viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1] animated:NO];
```

Check your Controller Structure. UINavigationController is needed.

> UITabBarController - UINavgationController - UIViewController

But I recommend make custom people picker controller using AddressBook Framework not AddressBookUI.

Without customizing, you can change only a few factor.

Comment: @MehulMistri why? check your tabbarcontrolloer structure. Make UITabBarController - UINavgationController - UIViewController not UITabBarController - UIViewController

Comment: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController is itself Navigationcontroller and we can't push navigationcontroller

Comment: and the structure is same as you suggested

Comment: oh sorry, UIViewController *pickerVC = [picker viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1]; you can get view controllers

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some code like this in the app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
UITabBarController *tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
tabBar.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewFor1stTab, viewForSecondTab, picker, nil];

[self.window add subview tabBar.view];
```

replace viewFor1stTab, viewForSecondTab with the views you want for those tabs.
Please read the documentation, this is probably the most basic function of UITabBarController.